# Flask redirect function not redirecting to the correct page

Tags: python, html, redirect, flask, https

I have the page app route. This is my python flask code.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
   return render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/dashboard", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    app.logger.debug(form.validate_on_submit())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect("dashboard")

    return render_template("registerPage.html", title="Register", forms=form)
```

When I run it it redirects to http://localhost:5000 when it should redirect to http://localhost:5000/dashboard.
Whats happening?

Comment: it should redirect to `dashboard` only when you are on `register` and you send correct values in `form`. I don't see any other redirections.

Comment: Sorry I missed some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an import for `url_for`:

```
from flask import url_for
```

Then use it in the redirect:

```
return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
```

The `url_for` function takes the name of a function and constructs the "url for" that function.

You posted a link to your project files on DropBox.

In your template, `registerPage.html`, you need to change:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/">
```

to:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/register">
```

If you post to `/` instead, the `register` function will never see the posted data and will never redirect the user to the dashboard.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, it still gives me a 404

Comment: Its redirecting to the function connected to `@app.route("/")` so in this case the home page.

Comment: Please try importing url_for and using that in the call to redirect.

Comment: I have but it gives an `The requested URL was not found on the server`.

Comment: Ok, let's see registerPage.html.  When you first go to /register, does it display the form?

Comment: If I remove the `@app.route("/")` it gives me that error however  when I add it, it redirects to the function that it is connected too.

Comment: It's working when I add the `@app.route("/")` to the register function, but I can't do that for all redirects. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: I am not sure there is a problem here.  I need to see the template code.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1j4mdr0gcpzlaql/AAAqymHiMcqP170ex2wqwT7Fa?dl=0

Comment: These are the project files